# Array to object function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

For the function Objectgenerator(input1, input2), take arrays as input. Each array must have only two elements. The goal is to use JavaScript to create an object that will have the first elements of each array as the key and the second element as the value. In the event more than one array has similar first elements, then consider only the value of the last one. For example:

Examples:

```
Objectgenerator(["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"],["key1","value3"]) would result in the following output --> {key1:"value3", key2:"value2"}

Objectgenerator(["Key1","value1"],["key2","value2"]) --> {key1:"value1",key2:"value2"}
```

Errors would result if the following parameters are passed:

```
Objectgenerator([])
Objectgenerator()
Objectgenerator('testing')
Objectgenerator(22)
Objectgenerator(['key1','valuea','valueb'],['key2','valuec'])
```

Comment: Sounds like interesting homework. What have you found in your research? What attempts have you made based on that research? There are thousands of questions on Stack Overflow about turning arrays into objects; have you looked at any of those?

Comment: What if the two elements of any of the inputs or any of them is not a string? An array? A number? An object? `Objectgenerator([2, 'rest'],[{first:'one'},'when'],['two',[3,'five']])`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Array#reduce` is your best bet. Setting it up is straight forward. The actual work is in verifying that the input is valid.

```js
function objectGenerator(...arr) {
    if( arr.length && 
        arr.every(el => Array.isArray(el) && el.length === 2) ) {
        return arr.reduce((obj, [key,value]) => ({...obj,[key]:value}),{});
    } else {
        const err = new Error('Input is not valid');
        throw err;
    }
}

console.log( objectGenerator(["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"],["key1","value3"]) );

console.log( objectGenerator(["Key1","value1"],["key2","value2"]) );
```